# ElasticSearch + Logstash works, but does not displays any data

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have an Oracle DB. Logstash retrieves data from Oracle and puts it to ElasticSearch. And everything looks fine, but no changes occur on the Logstash server, as if it doesn't know what to do.

**logstash.conf:**

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_library => "C:\JBoss\wildfly\...\ojdbc7.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@3d-ztemtis-ora.iba:1521/ORCL"
        jdbc_user => "sample_user"
        jdbc_password => "12345"
        jdbc_validate_connection => true

        # once a 2 minute
        schedule => "2 * * * *"
        statement => "SELECT * FROM table_one"
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
        index => "tableone"
        document_id => "%{uid}"
    }
    stdout{
    codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

**Logstash logs**

```
D:\Workspace3\ElasticLogstash\logstash-6.5.1>bin\logstash -f logstash.conf
Sending Logstash logs to D:/Workspace3/ElasticLogstash/logstash-6.5.1/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2018-11-28T00:49:30,296][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2018-11-28T00:49:30,308][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"6.5.1"}
[2018-11-28T00:49:33,174][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>8, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50}
[2018-11-28T00:49:33,455][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://localhost:9200/]}}
[2018-11-28T00:49:33,471][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Running health check to see if an Elasticsearch connection is working {:healthcheck_url=>http://localhost:9200/, :path=>"/"}
[2018-11-28T00:49:33,625][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://localhost:9200/"}
[2018-11-28T00:49:33,674][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>6}
[2018-11-28T00:49:33,674][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>6}
[2018-11-28T00:49:33,699][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//localhost:9200"]}
[2018-11-28T00:49:33,718][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Using mapping template from {:path=>nil}
[2018-11-28T00:49:33,745][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"template"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>60001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s"}, "mappings"=>{"_default_"=>{"dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}}
[2018-11-28T00:49:33,940][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline started successfully {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x64e24d22 run>"}
[2018-11-28T00:49:33,971][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
[2018-11-28T00:49:34,217][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
```

**ElasticSearch log**

```
[2018-11-28T00:36:06,492][DEBUG][o.e.a.ActionModule       ] [px9stLj] Using REST wrapper from plugin org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.Security
[2018-11-28T00:36:06,683][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [px9stLj] using discovery type [zen] and host providers [settings]
[2018-11-28T00:36:07,188][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [px9stLj] initialized
[2018-11-28T00:36:07,188][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [px9stLj] starting ...
[2018-11-28T00:36:07,387][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [px9stLj] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9300}, {[::1]:9300}
[2018-11-28T00:36:10,500][INFO ][o.e.c.s.MasterService    ] [px9stLj] zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined), reason: new_master {px9stLj}{px9stLjKSkqdyzudpK1ZhA}{bkR2txqXTn-Eo1o7-2PqEA}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{ml.machine_memory=17058418688, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.enabled=true}
[2018-11-28T00:36:10,500][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterApplierService] [px9stLj] new_master {px9stLj}{px9stLjKSkqdyzudpK1ZhA}{bkR2txqXTn-Eo1o7-2PqEA}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{ml.machine_memory=17058418688, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.enabled=true}, reason: apply cluster state (from master [master {px9stLj}{px9stLjKSkqdyzudpK1ZhA}{bkR2txqXTn-Eo1o7-2PqEA}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{ml.machine_memory=17058418688, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.enabled=true} committed version [1] source [zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)]])
[2018-11-28T00:36:10,585][INFO ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4HttpServerTransport] [px9stLj] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9200}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9200}, {[::1]:9200}
[2018-11-28T00:36:10,585][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [px9stLj] started
[2018-11-28T00:36:10,921][WARN ][o.e.x.s.a.s.m.NativeRoleMappingStore] [px9stLj] Failed to clear cache for realms [[]]
[2018-11-28T00:36:10,962][INFO ][o.e.l.LicenseService     ] [px9stLj] license [852e276a-f99f-4ce3-a5d6-86c7769ae24e] mode [basic] - valid
[2018-11-28T00:36:10,970][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [px9stLj] recovered [3] indices into cluster_state
[2018-11-28T00:36:12,366][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [px9stLj] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards started [[blog][0]] ...]).
```

As I said, the problem is - nothing is happens and no errors logged.
How can I know is this succesfully connected to Oracle?

Comment: Run the logstash and elasticsearch  in debug mode and see the logs

Comment: @IjazAhmadKhan Well, I'll check it out. But may be you know, why do Logstash server waits over 20 minutes before it makes any call to DB?

Comment: Are u sure the logstash is using ur logstash.conf or something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the schedule examples here:

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-run-the-schedule-every-five-minutes-in-logstash-5-0/66222

https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/cron-every-5-minutes/

I think your schedule section should look like this:

Every 2 minutes

```
schedule => "*/2 * * * *"
```

Comment: Yes, I thought  "2 * * * *" is 2 minutes. Great, thank you!